# SQL Reports Drop Down limit?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am trying to run a report against a dataset of over one million records, the rules I have been supplied with for the report are as follows the report must be able to filter each drop down filters contents with the selection of the provious drop down.

The SQL Report that had previously been put in place for this task is now failing the raeson is escaping me at the moment. The report seems to do some kind of auto postback upon changing the first drop down, mostly the selected values from the first drop down are cleared and I cannot find a shred of evidence as to why. The only lead I have is the large amount of data and the fact there are around 1500 slections in the first drop down. any takers?

```
SELECT     Employee, 
           CONVERT(nvarchar(30), Date, 103) AS Date, Duration, Level, 
           Area, Dept, Cell, Line, Slot, ISNULL(Activity, '') AS Activity, 
           Area1, Surname, WeekEnding 
           FROM LabourBooking
           WHERE (Slot IN (@Slot)) 
           AND (Date BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo) 
           AND (Area1 IN (@Area)) 
           AND (Activity IN (@Activity))
           ORDER BY SURNAME, Employee
```

I have edited to supply the SQL that is used

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: how can I stop the refresh happening in the drop down and losing all the previiously selected data?

Comment: @Deviland: Is the query for the dataset used in the first parameter dropdown dependant on one of the other parameters? Can you add the text of the query for that first parameter's dropdown dataset to the question?

Comment: If subsequent parameters depend on the first, then you need the refresh, correct? The problem is losing the selected data, which is unusual. Does it work in BIDS?

Comment: @Jamie F exactly the problem I am sure it is to do with the amount of data that first query is bringing back just over 1500 results. Sotrry you lost me with the BIDS reference?

Comment: @Mark Bannister Not quite the selection in the first drop down is set for the other drop downs inb the report.

Comment: @Deviland: What is the query that you have added to the question? Is it the query for the main report? What about the query for the first parameter? Which of those parameters is the first parameter?

Comment: @Mark Bannister this is the report but I have solved the problem by rewriting the report and all sub queries to stop excessive loading thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to rewrite the report